# spring boot tool suite installation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

after have downloaded the jar ex-tractable[image] file, and extracted it successfully but i was unable to run the springtoolsuite4.exe application the error message was show in the attached screenshot... please what should i do? have try moving the extracted file to C:/ but the error insist the name of the extracted folder was sts-4.5.1.RELEASE extracted from spring-tool-suite-4-4.5.1.RELEASE-e4.14.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar

Comment: you had better try to install STS 3.9.10

Answer (score 0):

Error code 13 indicates that the bit version is faulty/different.. You are maybe trying to install a 32 bit version on 64bit machine.. Another thing that you can try is checking the jdk version because this may cause the issue as well. All that is briefly described in the following [article](https://tech4grasp.com/java-was-started-but-returned-exist-code-13-in-stssolved/)!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might try to run your Spring Tools 4 with a 32bit JDK or an older, non-supported version of the JDK. Please install a recent JDK 8 or older and configure that in your SpringTools4.ini file, like described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Spring Suit can not find the correct Java application launcher or is a bit confused about Java bit version, either 64-bit or 32-bit.

You better insert JDK path in the file `.ini`, just between the lines starting with `openfile` and `-vmargs`, like shown below;

```
...
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
...
```